# How to get LinkLabel text from some List of strings with loop?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, hyperlink, linklabel

If I have for example linklabel1, linklabel2, linklabel3....linklabel10. 
And some list of string that count 10 item.

How do I pass each strings(first string it's going to be text in linklabel1, second string in linklabel2....) in than link label with loop?

Comment: Write some code and try to fix the problem. If you couldn't post the question including code to reproduce the problem. Take a look at [ASK] and [MCVE] as well.

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question yet?

Answer (score 0):

Asuming it's windows forms use [Control.ControlCollection.Find.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(VS.80).aspx)

This allows you to find a GUI component by string name
meaning you can use a for loop and add i+1 to "linklabel" find the LinkLabel using .Find and then alter the .Text value using the string on index i from your list